# unwanted change a data in a filter algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, filter, arduino

I have written the simple linear median filter code in C++ programming language. I have a severe problem, in the part of this filter my data will change and the result of this filter does not make any sense. I have found in which part this occurrence happened but I have no idea how to fix this problem. I mean when I print the data in the commented line I wil l get the wrong answer. For instance , the result of buffer_data[1] in the first deceleration of this value is 51 but this result in the commented lines becomes 1434234133123 or so on.

```
double median_filter( int data, int counter){
  int sum=0;
  double result=0;
  static int buffer_length=8;
  int buffer_data[buffer_length];
  int temp=0;

// first time initiation

      if (counter==1){
          for (int i=1;i<=buffer_length;i++){
            buffer_data[i]=0;
          }
      }

      if (counter <= buffer_length){
      buffer_data[counter]=data;
      }

      /* this part of the code changes the data of the buffer or so on

      else{
            for (int i=1;i<=(buffer_length-1);i++){             
              buffer_data[i]=buffer_data[i+1];
            }
            buffer_data[buffer_length]=data;
      }

     */ 
           for (int i=1;i<=buffer_length;i++){
            sum=sum+(buffer_data[i]);
           }

           if (counter<= buffer_length)
           result=double(sum/counter);
           else
           result=double(sum/buffer_length);

           return (result);
}
```

Update[1]

I have fixed your precious comments, but still the problem exist. Here is the fixed code based on your comments.

```
double median_filter( int data, int counter){
  int sum=0;
  double result=0;
  int buffer_data[8];
  int temp=0;
// first time initiation
      if (counter==1){
          for (int i=0;i<=(7);i++){
            buffer_data[i]=0;
          }
      }

        if (counter <= (7)){
          buffer_data[counter]=data;          
        }
      //this part of the code changes the data of the buffer or so on
      else{
            for (int i=0;i<=(6);i++){             
              buffer_data[i]=buffer_data[i+1];
            }
            buffer_data[7]=data;
      }

           for (int i=0;i<=(7);i++){
              sum=sum+(buffer_data[i]);
           }

           if (counter< (7))
           result=double(sum/(counter+1));
           else
           result=double(sum/8);

           return (result);
}
```

Comment: Arrays in C++ are `0` based `for (int i=1;i<=buffer_length;i++)` -> `for (int i=0;i<buffer_length;i++)` ...  etc lots of places and probably other knock-on code changes will be required.

Comment: I don't know if it helps or not, but is this fact working for arduino IDE too?

Comment: Undefined behavior sometimes have the unfortunate effect of *seemingly* working.

Comment: Also, C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), like your array `buffer_data`. Some compilers might add it as an *extension*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your answers but the problem was another thing.
I had created an array with the type of "int" with total length of 64 bytes, while I had filled this array with the 2 bytes variable and that was the problem.
I changed the type of the buffer_data from int to uint8_t and the problem solved.

Also thanks for your support.